# Posting multiple forms in ncurses: only last form is initially visible

Tags: c++, curses

I have a few sets of forms within my ncurses program. Each field has A_UNDERLINE enabled but I noticed that only the last form posted will show underlines until I navigate to it; the others are simply blank space.

I would like to ensure all the fields appear with underlines as soon as I refresh my pad.
Eventually, I intend to allow users to add and remove fields within a form and will compile all field contents within a form together for analysis. Therefore putting all the fields into one form is possible but not ideal at all.

Since I'm new to curses, I'm a little lost as to what I should even be trying. I've tried calling `form_driver(form, REQ_END_LINE);` for each form prior to looping on input to no avail. As well as `form_driver(form, REQ_NEXT_FIELD);` since that seemed to work inside the input loop.

I'm clearly missing something but I'm not sure if I haven't correctly initialized my fields/forms or if I'm simply misunderstanding how these work.

I've created a simplified version of the issue below:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <form.h>

int main()
{
    WINDOW *pad;
    FIELD *field[3];
    FORM  *my_form;
    FIELD *field_two[3];
    FORM *form_two;
    int ch;

    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    pad = newpad(LINES,COLS);
    keypad(pad, TRUE);

    field[0] = new_field(1, 10, 4, 18, 0, 0);
    field[1] = new_field(1, 10, 6, 18, 0, 0);
    field[2] = NULL;

    field_two[0] = new_field(1, 10, 8, 18, 0, 0);
    field_two[1] = new_field(1, 10, 10, 18, 0, 0);
    field_two[2] = NULL;

    set_field_back(field[0], A_UNDERLINE);
    set_field_back(field[1], A_UNDERLINE);

    set_field_back(field_two[0], A_UNDERLINE);
    set_field_back(field_two[1], A_UNDERLINE);

    wclear(pad);
    my_form = new_form(field);
    set_form_sub(my_form, pad);
    post_form(my_form);

    form_two = new_form(field_two);
    set_form_sub(form_two, pad);
    post_form(form_two);

    mvwprintw(pad, 1, 1, "Some text");
    mvwprintw(pad, 4, 10, "Value 1:");
    mvwprintw(pad, 6, 10, "Value 2:");
    mvwprintw(pad, 8, 10, "Value 3:");
    mvwprintw(pad, 10, 10, "Value 4:");
    prefresh(pad, 0, 0, 0, 0, LINES, COLS);

    bool form1 = true;
    while((ch = getch()) != KEY_F(1))
    {
        switch(ch)
        {   case KEY_DOWN:
                if (form1) {
                    form_driver(my_form, REQ_NEXT_FIELD);
                    form_driver(my_form, REQ_END_LINE);
                } else {
                    form_driver(form_two, REQ_NEXT_FIELD);
                    form_driver(form_two, REQ_END_LINE);
                }
                break;
            case KEY_UP:
                if (form1) {
                    form_driver(my_form, REQ_PREV_FIELD);
                    form_driver(my_form, REQ_END_LINE);
                } else {
                    form_driver(form_two, REQ_PREV_FIELD);
                    form_driver(form_two, REQ_END_LINE);
                }

                break;
            case KEY_RIGHT:
                form1 = false;
                break;
            case KEY_LEFT:
                form1 = true;
                break;
            default:
                if (form1) {
                    form_driver(my_form, ch);
                } else {
                    form_driver(form_two, ch);
                }
                break;
        }
        prefresh(pad, 0, 0, 0, 0, LINES, COLS);
    }

    unpost_form(my_form);
    free_form(my_form);
    free_field(field[0]);
    free_field(field[1]);
    unpost_form(form_two);
    free_form(form_two);
    free_field(field_two[0]);
    free_field(field_two[1]);
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

When the above is executed, I have a blank screen until I press a key (if you feel like pointing out why that is I'd like to hear but that's not the point of this question). After that, I see the fields for Value 3 and Value 4 have underlines but Value 1 and Value 2 do not until I start typing in them.

My goal here is to have underlines for fields on the same lines as Value 1 and Value 2 without any additional user input.

Comment: offhand - only one **form** is posted, but you can make a [multi-**page**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/form_page.3x.html) form as done in ncurses-examples [demo_forms.c](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/c34b0439ddc07ac2b4de9aab7e58592d7af4490c/test/demo_forms.c#L433)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish my goal of all fields being underlined by adding the following code immediately under `post_form(form_two);`

```
    set_field_back(field[0], 0);
    set_field_back(field[1], 0);
    set_field_back(field[0], A_UNDERLINE);
    set_field_back(field[1], A_UNDERLINE);
```